# Set a default value to Class property in CoffeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I try to set a default value for a given class property.

```
class MyClass
    name: (name = 'value') ->
```

The code above doesn't return `value`. It returns the whole function.

```
a = new MyClass
a.name
> function (name) {
if (name == null) name = 'value';
}
```

If I set a value to it then it works:

```
a = new MyClass
a.name = 'something'
a.name
> 'something'
```

I'm wondering what would be the proper way to set a default value for a Class property in CoffeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
class MyClass
    name: (name = 'value') ->
```

simply defines `name` as a method which takes one parameter, also called `name`, and the default value for that parameter is `'value'`. So, if we add a body and execute the method:

```
class MyClass
    name: (name = 'value') ->
        console.log(name)
new MyClass().name()
new MyClass().name('pancakes')
```

You'll see `'value'` and `'pancakes'` in the console. [Here's a demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20MyClass%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%28name%20%3D%20%27value%27%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28name%29%0Anew%20MyClass%28%29.name%28%29%0Anew%20MyClass%28%29.name%28%27pancakes%27%29), open your console to see what happens.

If you want instances of `MyClass` to have a name property whose default value is `'value'` then you want to say this:

```
class MyClass
    constructor: (@name = 'value')
console.log(new MyClass().name)
console.log(new MyClass('pancakes').name)
```

That will also [give you `'value'` and `'pancakes'`](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20MyClass%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@name%20=%20%27value%27%29%20-%3E%0Aconsole.log%28new%20MyClass%28%29.name%29%0Aconsole.log%28new%20MyClass%28%27pancakes%27%29.name%29) in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a default value in the constructor?

```
class MyClass
  constructor: (@name = 'default') ->
```

If you want to set a property on the actual MyClass function you could do:

```
class MyClass
  @Name = 'value'
```

but I suspect that isn't what you meant.